# Does the winrt namespace have console functions?

Tags: c++, console, windows-console, c++-winrt

I searched the documentation for the `winrt` namespace and didn't find any  console functions, i.e `AttachConsole`. I wonder if there is, for a UWP windows console project (C++/winrt)?

Answer (score 0):

UWP has three 'app models':

- A XAML app with C# or C++ code-behind
- A Direct3D app
- A Direct3D + XAML app

There is no support for 'console windows' in UWP.

> I've 'faked' a text console for UWP test apps and samples using the Direct3D app model (see [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for the basic render loop), [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started), and my [TextConsole](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/TextConsole) utility.

Comment: [Console UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp) seem to be a new addition to Windows 10, version 1803.

Comment: The point is that there are no new WinRT console APIs, so you can continue to use whatever console APIs/libraries you were using before.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke most Windows Runtime APIs from any win32 console applications as well as packaged console applications (a relatively new feature) but there are no Windows Runtime APIs that provide control of the console or console-specific behavior at this time.

Thanks,

Ben (MSFT)